# I want to set an onClickListener for a button in the page of my viewpager

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am developing an app which consists of a view-pager which has just 2 pages and LinearLayouts in each of those pages. I want to set click listeners for those linearlayouts.

I implemented the view pager by using  PagerAdapter. I tried

```
view.findViewById(R.id.add_new_tut_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

But it doesn't work at all

HomePagerAdapter.java

```java
public class HomePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    HomePagerAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        final ModelObject modelObject = ModelObject.values()[position];
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(modelObject.getLayoutResId(), container, false);
        View view = inflater.inflate( modelObject.getLayoutResId(), container, false);
        if ( position == 0) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.add_new_tut_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

        container.addView(layout);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ModelObject.values().length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    public enum ModelObject{
        HOME_PAGE("Home", R.layout.home_btns_layout),
        FILES_PAGE("Files", R.layout.files_download_layout);

        private int mLayoutResId;
        private String mTitleResId;

        ModelObject(String titleResId, int layoutResId) {
            mTitleResId = titleResId;
            mLayoutResId = layoutResId;
        }

        public String getTitleResId() {
            return mTitleResId;
        }

        public int getLayoutResId()
        {
            return mLayoutResId;
        }
    }

}
```

home_btns_layout.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/files_view">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/add_new_tut_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/st_home_btn_bg_1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Find"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/upcoming_tut_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/st_home_btn_bg_1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Upcoming"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

files_download_layout.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/st_home_btn_bg_1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Networks"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/st_home_btn_bg_1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp">



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Theories"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/st_home_btn_bg_1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Questions"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please add what you mean by *it is not working at all*? What is the exact error you are getting? Knowing that makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Cant help but notice you inflate your view twice, once as `view` and set listener to the button there and once as `layout` and attach layout to pager. Those are separate instances.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I hadn't even noticed it. @IcedLance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a foolish mistake. I inflated the view twice, set the listener on one and appended another to the ViewGroup container. Thank you for pointing it out @IcedLance

Answer (score 1):

Can i suggest to use Fragments for each screen of your ViewPager ? then inside your Fragment you can do whatever you want, with all ClickListeners tat you need.

I have created a gist for you[gist ViewPagerAdapter](https://gist.github.com/matteopasotti/e00e2c4562ccdc2057322061aa51cf4e)

Comment: could you please share the java version of the same?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly tell android that you require your linearlayout to be clickable! Because it is a layout and not a widget.

Setting the LinearLayout **clickable attribute** to true.

In XML

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Or in Code

```
yourLinearLayoutButton.setClickable(true);
```